# detect unconsumed command key on form - winforms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a form with several input controls (comboboxes, textboxes). I would like to close the form on the escape key but only if input controls didn't consume the keypress. Let's say focus is on an open (dropped down) combobox. Pressing Esc will close up the dropdown portion of the combobox - thus, I don't want to close the form. But if the combobox is not open pressing Esc  won't not do anything with the combobox so I would like to close the form.
I've thought that overriding form's ProcessCmdKey will do the job. I've tried

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    bool consumed = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    if (!consumed)
        Close();
}
```

But 'consumed' was always false (in my test cases) regardless of anything has happened of form's controls or not.
Maybe this is a bad approach and I don't need to override ProcessCmdKey but I have to do something else.

How can it be done?

Comment: Try overriding [`ProcessDialogKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. And of course don't forget to check for `ESC` key.

Comment: Why would you need that. In modal WinForms dialog, you can associate Esc by adding a Cancel button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Ivan Stoev's comment ProcessDialogKey seems to be the good solution.

Form:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    bool consumed = base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    if (!consumed && keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Close();
        consumed = true;
    }
    return consumed;
}
```

The above alone is enough to work with ComboBox as I asked in the question.
However, if you've added for example some undo functionality to a TextBox's to react to Esc and you want to make work TextBox a similar way (if an undo was done then do not close the form, when no undo was possible then close the form) you need to override TextBox's ProcessDialogKey as well, eg:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        bool undoWasDone = Undo();
        if (undoWasDone)
            return true;
    } 
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```